# Catching file name

Tags: python

I'm writing a Python 3.4 script.  In the directory I have:

```
main.py
core.py
```

In `main.py` I have:

```
import core
print(core.status())
```

In `core.py` I have:

```
def status():
    return filename
```

Which I want the `filename` which imported `core.status()`.  Here is `filename='main.py'` because I use `core.status()` in lots of files, it is not good to use `__main__` .

Is it possible to catch the filename which imported another function and print it inside the function as I explained above?

Comment: Why do it that way around, not `core.status(__name__)`? What if `import core` happens more than once from different places? Why do you need to know it at all?

Comment: thanks. as you said i can use:`core.status(__file__)`. it is correct but i wanted to  know if there is another way?

Comment: *To what end?* What are you actually trying to achieve with this. Generally, modules shouldn't know or care where they're imported from.

Comment: im implenting a advanced debugger that prevents the program to be closed when there is a exception. and in my program i have lots of exceptions. so when i want to troubleshoot, i need to know the files'because my programs dont give me error.'

Comment: so you want to know where the error came from? That info is in the traceback.

Comment: when im using try and except there is no traceback!

Comment: There is in the error you catch; how do you think the interpreter does it?! In fact, maybe you should look into the interpreter, and `pdb` module, which might give you some ideas.

Comment: ok thanks.i'll take a look at it.@jonrsharpe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract this from the stack trace:

```
import traceback


def status():
    print(traceback.extract_stack(limit=2)[-2][0])
```

`-2` just means the second last entry of the stack, i.e. what called `status()`.

I'm guessing what you mean by import is to call.

Answer (score 1):

To get the filename of the caller, you can use `psutil`

```
import psutil

def status():
    callee = psutil.Process()
    caller = psutil.Process(callee.ppid())
    return caller.cmdline()
```

Or `sys.exc_info` :

```
import sys

def status():
    print sys.exc_info()[2].tb_frame.f_code.co_filename
```

Comment: not working for me if using pycharm,idle or... but it works.